# link will work only on 1st click and from 2nd click will not redirect to the page which is specified in href

Tags: javascript

I want this link will work only on 1st click. From 2nd click it will not redirect to a.php and will stay on the same page after hitting the hyperlink.

```
<script>
  var j=0;
  function a()
  {
      if(j==0)
      {
          window.location.href="a.php";
          j=1;
      }
      else
      {
           window.location.href="t.html";
      }

  }
 </script>
<a href="a.php" onclick="a()">hi</a>
```

Comment: What isn't working about it? Assuming this is part of a page called "t.html", by a quick glance, it looks to me like it should work.

Comment: it is not working.1st page is t.html

Comment: I just made myself a page with this code in it, and it's working as expected. If I click the link once it redirects to a.php. I can't seem to double click it fast enough before it redirects, but I think if I could it would stay on the page. Once I reload the page the code resets.

Comment: when i redirect to t.html from a.php and will click on hyperlink then also it will redirect to a.php but i want it will stay on t.html page fron 2nd time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @Okx said was pretty correct, however using the `localStorage` will work just fine on every browser starting from IE8.

```
function a() {
  var count = parseInt(localStorage.count_of_a, 10); 
  if (isNaN(count)) count = 0; 
  if (count == 0) {
    count += 1; 
    localStorage.count_of_a = count;
    window.location = 'a.php';
  } else {
    window.location = 't.html'; 
  }
}
// Note 1: this won't work if Javascript is disabled!
// Note 2: people can reset their local storage and rewrite the variables
//         themselves!
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because your browser deletes all the `JavaScript` variables when you leave the page.

I suggest using **JavaScript cookies**. Then you can keep those variables until the browser deletes all the `cookie`s.
To set a `cookie`, call the following method::

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
}
```

...and to get a cookie:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```